# Why drop down event is not working asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having drop down list its event(not displaying hello) is not working ....

aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

aspx.cs page

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

problem is if i keep break point in console.writeline its not working...where i made error...any idea.thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AutoPostBack="true"` in your aspx code like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

// Add  AutoPostBack.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct except for one thing. the event will trigger only if this status is true

set

```
AutoPostBack = "true"

//Actual code
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```